# How to transition linear gradient for a path

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, dom-events

I'm working on a sankey diagram that updates whenever I change the filter (radiobuttons) using d3.js and a sankey-plugin. Now I'm trying to add a feature that, whenever I hover over one of the path, I append a linear gradient to the path going from the color of the source node to the color of the target node. If I don't use the filter everything works fine, however the gradient-coloring doesn't work if I apply the filter (colors are set wrong) because the links are transitioned. I think that I have to transition the linear-gradient somehow, but I don't understand how I have to do this.

I wrote a little script that shows the problem, before clicking the button colors are correct, and after it's messed up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-sankey@0.6"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="diagram" height="150" width="600"></svg>
    <button onclick="updateSankey()">Click Me!</button>

    <style>
        #diagram{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        var target = 0;
        var sankeyLinks;
        var sankeyData = {nodes:[], links:[]};

        calculateLinks();
        initSankey();
        updateSankey();

        function initSankey() {
            /*simple initialisation of the sankey, should explain itself*/

            svg = d3.select("svg"),
                width = +svg.attr("width"),
                height = +svg.attr("height");

            formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
                format = function (d) { return formatNumber(d) + " %"; },
                color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

            sankey = d3.sankey()
                .nodeWidth(15)
                .nodePadding(10)
                .extent([[1, 1], [width - 1, height - 6]])
                .iterations(0);

            t = d3.transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear);

            //set attributes for all links
            titleGroup = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "titles")
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "150%");

            diagram= svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "sankey")
               // .attr("transform", "translate(" + marginleft + "," + margintop + ")");

            linkGroup = diagram.append("g")
                .attr("class", "links")
                .attr("fill", "none");
            //.attr("stroke", "#000")
            //.attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2);

            //set attributes for all nodes
            nodeGroup = diagram.append("g")
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", 10);
        }

        function calculateLinks() {
            if(target == 0)
            {
                target = 1;
                sankeyLinks = [{source:0, target:1, value:5},{source:0, target:2, value:10},{source:0, target:3, value:15}];
            }
            else
            {
                target = 0;
                sankeyLinks = [{source:0, target:2, value:15},{source:0, target:1, value:20},{source:0, target:3, value:10}];
            }
        }

        function updateSankey() {
            calculateLinks();
            sankeyData.links = sankeyLinks;
            sankeyData.nodes =  [{name: "first"}, {name:"second"}, {name:"third"}, {name: "fourth"}];
            sankey(sankeyData);

            var links = linkGroup.selectAll('path')
                .data(sankeyData.links);

            //Set attributes for each link separately
            links.enter().append("g")
                .attr("id",function (d,i) {return "path"+i;})
                .append("path")
                .attr("stroke", "#000")
                .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.15)
                .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
                .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {return Math.max(1, d.width); })
                .on("mouseover",function (d,id) {
                    var pathGroup = svg.select('#path' + id);
                    var path = pathGroup.select("path");

                    path.attr("stroke","url(#grad"+id+")")
                        .attr("stroke-opacity","0.95");
                })
                .on("mouseout",function (d, id) {
                    pathGroup = svg.select('#path' + id);
                    var path = pathGroup.select("path");

                    path.attr("stroke","#000")
                        .attr("stroke-opacity","0.15");
                })
                .append("title")
                .text(function (d) {
                    //tooltip info for the links
                    return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            var pathGradient = svg.select(".links")
                .selectAll("g")
                .append("defs")
                .append("linearGradient")
                .attr("id",function (d, id) {
                    return "grad" + id;
                })
                //.attr("from", function () {return this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].getAttribute("from");})
                //.attr("to", function () {return this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].getAttribute("to");})
                .attr("gradientUnit","userSpaceOnUse")
                .attr("style","mix-blend-mode: multiply;")
                .attr("x1","0%")
                .attr("x2","100%")
                .attr("y1","0%")
                .attr("y2","0%");

            pathGradient.append("stop")
                .attr("class","from")
                .attr("offset","0%")
                .attr("style", function (d) {
                    var color = setColor(d.source);
                    return "stop-color:" + color + ";stop-opacity:1";
                });

            pathGradient.append("stop")
                .attr("class","to")
                .attr("offset","100%")
                .attr("style",function (d) {
                    var color = setColor(d.target);
                    return "stop-color:" + color + ";stop-opacity:1";
                });

            links.transition(t)
                .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
                .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.max(1, d.width); })
                .select('title')
                .text(function (d) {
                    //same argumentation as above, we need the method again for the transition
                    return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            links.exit().remove();

            var nodes = nodeGroup.selectAll('.node')
                .data(sankeyData.nodes);

            var nodesEnter = nodes.enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr('class', 'node');

            //set attributes for each node separately
            nodesEnter.append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x0; })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y0; })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
                .attr("width", function (d) {
                    var width = d.x1 - d.x0;
                    return width;
                })
                .attr("fill", setColor)
                .attr("stroke", "#000")
                .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)

            //specify Pop-Up when hovering over node
            nodesEnter.append("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            //Update selection
            var nodesUpdate = nodes.transition(t);

            //same as the links we have to state the methods again in the update
            nodesUpdate.select("rect")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y0; })
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x0; })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; });

            nodesUpdate.select("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            //Exit selection
            nodes.exit().remove();
        }

        function setColor(d) {
            switch (d.name) {
                case "first":
                    return "#f00";
                case "second":
                    return "#ff0";
                case "third":
                    return "#f0f";
                case "fourth":
                    return "#0ff";
                default:
                    return "#0f0";
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After clicking the button once, the path from the red to the purple node has a linear gradient from red to yellow, even though I'd like it to go from red to purple.

I already realised, that I could write e.g. `.iterations(15)` instead of `.iterations(0)` in `initSankey()` to fix this. In the actual project I can't do this since I have to force the order of the nodes.

I hope I am clear enough in my explanation, if not, feel free to ask.

I would be extremely pleased if someone could tell me how to fix this problem.

PS. in this snippet the link on top disappears on hover, I have fixed this in the real project, here it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue was that the gradient urls were based on i, which could be different for a particular link with each update (ie, the order of the links may be different, so have a different i value); and data updates were not based on a constant unique id for a link.

In the snippet, I've added a unique name value for the links in the calculateLinks function, which is then used for the data joins and creating the def gradients, which means they remain constant with each update.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-sankey"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="diagram" height="150" width="600"></svg>
    <button onclick="updateSankey()">Click Me!</button>

  
    <style>
        #diagram{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        var target = 0;
        var sankeyLinks;
        var sankeyData = {nodes:[], links:[]};

        calculateLinks();
        initSankey();
        updateSankey();

        function initSankey() {

            svg = d3.select("svg"),
                width = +svg.attr("width"),
                height = +svg.attr("height");

            formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
                format = function (d) { return formatNumber(d) + " %"; },

            sankey = d3.sankey()
                .nodeWidth(15)
                .nodePadding(10)
                .size([width - 1, height - 6])

            t = d3.transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear);

            //set attributes for all links
            titleGroup = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "titles")
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "150%");

            diagram= svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "sankey")
            
            svg.append("defs")
               
            linkGroup = diagram.append("g")
                .attr("class", "links")
                .attr("fill", "none");

            //set attributes for all nodes
            nodeGroup = diagram.append("g")
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", 10);
        }

        function calculateLinks() {
            if(target == 0)
            {
                target = 1;
                sankeyLinks = [
                  {name: "firstsecond",source:0, target:1, value:5},
                  {name: "firstthird",source:0, target:2, value:10},
                  {name: "firstfourth",source:0, target:3, value:15}];
            }
            else
            {
                target = 0;
                sankeyLinks = [
                  {name: "firstthird", source:0, target:2, value:15},
                  {name: "firstsecond", source:0, target:1, value:20},
                  {name: "firstfourth", source:0, target:3, value:10}
                ];
            }
        }

        function updateSankey() {
            calculateLinks();
            sankeyData.links = sankeyLinks;
            sankeyData.nodes =  [{name: "first"}, {name:"second"}, {name:"third"}, {name: "fourth"}];
            sankey(sankeyData);
         
          
          var pathGradient = svg.select("defs").selectAll("linearGradient")
             .data(sankeyData.links, function(d){ return d.name })
             .enter()
                .append("linearGradient")
                .attr("id",function (d) {
                    return "grad" + d.name;
                })
                .attr("gradientUnit","userSpaceOnUse")
                .attr("x1","0%")
                .attr("x2","100%")
                .attr("y1","0%")
                .attr("y2","0%");

            pathGradient.append("stop")
                .attr("class","from")
                .attr("offset","0%")
                .attr("style", function (d) {
                    var color = setColor(d.source);
                    return "stop-color:" + color;
                });

            pathGradient.append("stop")
                .attr("class","to")
                .attr("offset","100%")
                .attr("style",function (d) {
                    var color = setColor(d.target);
                    return "stop-color:" + color;
                });

            var links = linkGroup.selectAll('path')
                .data(sankeyData.links, function(d){ return d.name });

            //Set attributes for each link separately
            var linksenter = links.enter()
              .append("g")
                .attr("id",function (d) {return "path" + d.name;})
                .append("path")
                .style("stroke", "#000")
                .style("stroke-opacity", 0.15)
                .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {return Math.max(1, d.width); })
                .on("mouseover",function (d) {
                    var pathGroup = svg.select('#path' + d.name);
                    var path = pathGroup.select("path");

                    path.style("stroke","url(#grad" + d.name + ")")
                        .style("stroke-opacity","0.95");
                })
                .on("mouseout",function (d, id) {
                    pathGroup = svg.select('#path' + d.source.name + d.target.name);
                    var path = pathGroup.select("path");

                    path.style("stroke","#000")
                        .style("stroke-opacity","0.15");
                })
      
      linksenter.merge(links).attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
            
            links.transition(t)
                .attr("d", d3.sankeyLinkHorizontal())
                .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.max(1, d.width); })
                .select('title')
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            var nodes = nodeGroup.selectAll('.node')
                .data(sankeyData.nodes, function(d){ return d.name });

            var nodesEnter = nodes.enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr('class', 'node');
      
           nodesEnter.append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x0; })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y0; })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; })
                .attr("width", function (d) {
                    var width = d.x1 - d.x0;
                    return width;
                })
                .attr("fill", setColor)
                .attr("stroke", "#000")
                .attr("fill-opacity", 0.5)

            //specify Pop-Up when hovering over node
            nodesEnter.append("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

            //Update selection
            var nodesUpdate = nodes.transition(t);

            //same as the links we have to state the methods again in the update
            nodesUpdate.select("rect")
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y0; })
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x0; })
                .attr("height", function (d) { return d.y1 - d.y0; });

            nodesUpdate.select("title")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

        }

        function setColor(d) {
            switch (d.name) {
                case "first":
                    return "#f00";
                case "second":
                    return "#ff0";
                case "third":
                    return "#f0f";
                case "fourth":
                    return "#0ff";
                default:
                    return "#0f0";
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```